# Common Lisp: Empty variable list for DO

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

According to the HyperSpec, for its page on `DO` (emphasis provided by me):

> do accepts an ***arbitrary*** number of iteration vars which are bound
>   within the iteration and stepped in parallel.

And yet it seems that `DO` cannot accept an empty variable list such as in here:

```
(do (())
    ((cond n) (end-result))
  (cond-1..
  (cond-2..))
```

Is it true that `DO` cannot accept an empty var list? Is there a reason for this? (I guess there's always `LOOP`).

I'm running SBCL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too many parenthesis. It would be:

```
(do () (condition return-value) forms)
```

Comment: Thanks, shame that I never thought of that. Is there a reason why, for the conditions, (()), (or (nil) for that matter), works as an infinite loop? That was the reason why I thought you needed to put (()) or (nil) for the var list.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for `DO` is defined in the Common Lisp standard:

```
do ({var | (var [init-form [step-form]])}*)
  (end-test-form result-form*)
  declaration*
 {tag | statement}*
```

You can look up any symbol using the [Common Lisp Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/X_Symbol.htm) and find the syntax for special operators and macros.

As you can see from the syntax, Lisp expects a list of variable forms. These can either be a variable or a list of var, an optional initialization form and an optional step form. With this syntax, you can use more than one variable with `DO`.

As you also can see, there is only a single list combining the end test and the result-forms.